# How to get list of movies in itunes podcast

Tags: api, itunes, podcast

I have a link to podcast on itunes that looks like this: http://itunes.apple.com/pl/podcast/[name]/[id].
How can I get list of movies from that podcast. 
I can see two ways. First is parsing html to retrieve informations. Second, much better, is using itunes api (http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html). However i am not able to use this api, so it returns list of movies from certain podcast. Can anybody provide guidelines?

Answer (score 0):

Itunes podcast is generated from rss feed. Address to this feed can be found in itunes page source. The best way is to just parse this feed and extract all needed data.